# NSPredicate on an NSArray of CGPoints

Tags: ios, nspredicate, cgrect, cgpoint

I have an NSArray of CGPoints.

I actually want to get the minimal CGRect that contains all the CGPoints in that array.
Is there already any iOS function to do this?

Otherwise I will have to manually fetch `minX, maxX, minY, maxY`, and construct my CGRect this way:

```
CGrectMake(minX, minY, maxX-minX, maxY-minY);
```

For this I need to filter the NSArray with an NSPredicate.

(I know, I could filter the array manually, but come on!...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API that does what you're asking.  You'll have to write it yourself.

It wouldn't be appropriate for `NSPredicate` anyway.  A predicate is for filtering values, not for constructing new values.

```
CGRect boundsOfPointArray(NSArray *array) {
    CGRect bounds = CGRectNull;
    for (NSValue *wrapper in array) {
        CGRect r = (CGRect){ wrapper.CGPointValue, CGSizeZero };
        bounds = CGRectUnion(bounds, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it (as long as it is true, that you cannot use NSPredicate to get the max,min values out of an NSArray of CGPoints).

Answer (score 1):

This question is very unclear. Do you mean you want to create a minimal CGRect that contains all the points you have in an array? If so, that is pretty simple, just iterate over the array of points keeping track of the minX, maxX, minY and maxY. eg

```
CGFloat minX = CGFLOAT_MAX;
CGFloat minY = CGFLOAT_MAX;
CGFloat maxX = -CGFLOAT_MAX;
CGFloat maxY = -CGFLOAT_MAX;

for (NSValue *v in pointsArray) {
    CGPoint p = [v CGPointValue];
    minX = fminf(minX, p.x);
    minY = fminf(minY, p.y);
    maxX = fmaxf(maxX, p.x);
    maxY = fmaxf(maxY, p.y);
}

CGRect r = CGRectMake(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
```

Comment: This is exactly my goal, but I was wondering if there were a more elegant approach using NSPredicate.

Comment: @Tark X and Y can be negative.  You need to initialize the maximums to `-CGFLOAT_MAX`.

Comment: @robmayoff quite right, I was not aware of the CGRectUnion function either, a much neater solution.

Comment: @user1423640 how would using an NSPredicate be more elegant?